# Django finds all static files except one - 404

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I had my static files working correctly until I tried to add this library
https://github.com/ierror/django-js-reverse

I followed the instructions from the page, but Django still can't find the new resource.

from settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_js_reverse',
    ...,
)
```

in my template

```
<script src="{% static 'django_js_reverse/js/reverse.js' %}"></script>
```

my directory structure looks like this

```
staticfiles/
    admin/
    dist/
    django_js_reverse/
        js/
            reverse.js
```

After running

```
python manage.py collectstatic
python manage.py runserver
```

I also tried to run the following according to the library instructions, but no luck

```
./manage.py collectstatic_js_reverse
```

Here's the output from runserver when I try to load the page.

```
[08/Mar/2015 19:12:33] "GET /static/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Mar/2015 19:12:33] "GET /static/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Mar/2015 19:12:33] "GET /static/django_js_reverse/js/reverse.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1697
[08/Mar/2015 19:12:33] "GET /static/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Mar/2015 19:12:33] "GET /static/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Mar/2015 19:12:33] "GET /static/custom.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

I can't figure out where the issue is. The static files settings are obviously set up correctly because all the other files are being loaded fine. I must be missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated\

UPDATE

I tried moving the reverse.js file to dist/ but it still returns a 404.

The permissions on all the files are the same

```
ls -la staticfiles/dist/js
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff  67155 Mar  8 15:06 bootstrap.js
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff  35601 Mar  8 15:06 bootstrap.min.js
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff    484 Mar  8 15:06 npm.js
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff   3258 Mar 10 10:31 reverse.js
```

Comment: `collectstatic` won't help if you are running `runserver`. Is `staticfiles` your `STATIC_ROOT` or one of `STATICFILES_DIRS`? Try copying the `reverse.js` file into `dist`, change the script src accordingly and check if that works.

Comment: Sometimes you might have problem with gif type of files. Try to  chmod +x  them :)

Comment: Can you post your `.gitignore`?

Comment: Also, did you add `urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^jsreverse/$', 'django_js_reverse.views.urls_js', name='js_reverse'),
)` to your urls.py?

Comment: Yes, I tried that with the same results. I shouldn't have to do that if I'm using it as a static file though. If I add that url pattern and change my template to {% url 'js_reverse' %} then it works through the view. I still don't understand why the satic file isn't being found though.

Comment: If I copy and paste the contents of reverse.js into a new file, it works perfectly fine... Doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 2):

Got same problem and tried everything. Url to js file seems legit but it isn't (with Django 1.9 at least).

I've changed it from

```
<script src="{% static 'django_js_reverse/js/reverse.js' %}"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="{% url 'js_reverse' %}"></script>
```

And you need this url pattern in urls.py for this solution

```
# import view
from django_js_reverse.views import urls_js

# and add this in url patterns
url(r'^jsreverse/$', 'django_js_reverse.views.urls_js', name='js_reverse'),
```

And now it's working without any problem . Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this same issue recently, here's how I solved it.

One possible solution is copying `reverse.js` into your static directory, in this case `BASE_DIR/static/`.

```
# set the JS-reverse output to the static dir
JS_REVERSE_OUTPUT_PATH=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

# update the script's path
<script src="{% static 'reverse.js' %}"></script>
```

Then:

```
./manage.py collectstatic_js_reverse
./manage.py runserver # or collectstatic
```

---

Another solution would be alternating between static file and views usage in the templates. Assuming that you've added the url, as explained in the [Przemysław Melnarowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523115/1309785)'s answer, and that `SERVE_STATIC` tells if static files are being served from django app (`./manage.py runserver`):

```
{% if SERVE_STATIC %}
    {# get script from view #}
    <script src="{% url 'js_reverse' %}"></script>
{% else %}
    {# get script from static file #}
    <script src="{% static 'django_js_reverse/js/reverse.js' %}"></script>
{% endif %}
```